# Youtube DL returns none for artist and track

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

I'm trying to extract info like the artist and track from YouTube videos, but the `youtube-dl` library is returning none for song and artist.

I've read that YouTube updated recently and `youtube-dl` just hasn't caught up with the update.

Is there any other way I could do this?

```
        # takes in a video url and extracts all the info about it
        youtube_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}"


        # we dont want all the logs and unnecessay stuff and we dont want the library to download the video, so...
        video = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'quiet': True}).extract_info(
           youtube_url, download=False
        )

        # now that we have the info we need, lets assign it to the variables artist, track

        artist = video['artist']
        track = video['track']
        print("song:", track)
        print("artist:", artist)
        return artist, track
```

The output is:

```
song: None
artist: None
```

Comment: The YouTube Data API has no endpoint that'll provide you the info you're looking for. Maybe you should open an issue on [youtube-dl's own issue tracker](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues).

Comment: Pretty sure that these kind of information is not obtainable by the provided API. You might write a web scraper for this task.